# Angular 4.4.7 Typescript 2.7.2 Getting TS1005: ';'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, gulp, gulp-typescript

I am unable to build my project getting a lot of errors about `lib.es6.d.ts`

> node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20605,14): error TS1005: ';' expected.

[image]

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "amd",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noResolve": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outDir": "dist/debug"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "./**/*.ts",
    "!./node_modules"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "jspm_packages",
    "typings",
    "dist",
    "typings/*",
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main",
    "Scripts"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "buildOnSave": true
}
```

npm ls typescript

```
+-- @angular/cli@6.2.9
| `-- @schematics/angular@0.8.9
|   `-- typescript@2.9.2 deduped
+-- gulp-typedoc@1.2.1
| `-- typedoc@0.3.12
|   `-- typescript@1.6.2
+-- gulp-typescript@2.14.1
| `-- typescript@1.8.10
+-- tslint@3.15.1 invalid: ">=5.0.0-dev" from node_modules/gulp-tslint
| `-- typescript@2.9.2 deduped
+-- typedoc@0.2.3
| `-- typescript@1.4.1
+-- typescript@2.9.2
`-- typings@1.5.0
  `-- typings-core@1.6.1
    `-- typescript@2.9.2 deduped
```

PS C:\WebProjects\COTT\COTT\OrderTemplateTool.Web>

Comment: Yikes, your `gulp-typescript` is about 7 years out of date. I bet if you updated that, you'd have a bit more luck.

Comment: I cant solve your problem as its a spiral of errors which i faced issues long back when i was asked to update an old angular4 project which was running in systemjs. I made a backup project in github [Reference](https://github.com/Raghav009/kendo-grid/blob/master/package.json) may be you can refer

Comment: @Jefferson, I have shared my thoughts about this issue, can you please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) in conditional types & [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) in typescript only gets added in 2.8 release. Prior release don't support this.

I have reproduced your issue with this [playground](https://typescript-play.js.org/?ts=2.7.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUwhAhgcwQLhtATgSzDRgF4YByACwQBsaQYB3EXGgE3IG4AoUSEGggB09NAApEydAgCUPbtygBPAA4IYAQQA8AFQA0AVQB8pGDpgIAHlARg2EGAZgB+MzExgEANwS4eQA). I have selected 2.7.2 as typescript version & can see exact error which you are seeing.

If I use typescript 2.8.1 as [here](https://typescript-play.js.org/?ts=2.8.1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUwhAhgcwQLhtATgSzDRgF4YByACwQBsaQYB3EXGgE3IG4AoUSEGggB09NAApEydAgCUPblACeABwQwAggB4AKgBoAqgD5SMbTAQAPKAjBsIMfTAD8pmJjAIAbglycgA), this error disappears. So if you want support of conditional types in your code, you have to upgrade to 2.8.1 at least.

Or you can completely remove conditional type declaration from your code.
Complete list of features which are introduced as a part of 2.8 are found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-28)

Comment: I am still getting the error using 2.8.1 is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @Jefferson, what code you are trying with 2.8.1 version? is it something different than one which is posted in question?

Answer (score 1):

I looks like you might have some mismatching versions of angular. Your title says Angular version 4.4.7. Your tree says angular-cli 6.2.9 and you typescript version on 2.7.2. Typescript requirements are going to be different for angular and angular-cli. I would align those versions first by either downgrading cli or upgrading angular. Then wipe your node_modules folder and do a fresh npm install. Helpful tool for angular/angular-cli upgrades [HERE](https://update.angular.io/)

Comment: I dont see anything about using typescript 2.7.2 and angular 4.4.7?

Comment: Apologies, I assumed the title of this question "Angular 4.4.7 Typescript 2.7.2 Getting TS1005: ';'" was referring to the version of angular and typescript that were being used. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct I just don’t see anything letting me know what version to use.

Comment: @Jefferson https://gist.github.com/LayZeeDK/c822cc812f75bb07b7c55d07ba2719b3

Comment: Check the original package.json file. for angular 4.4.7 the angular cli version is ~1.3.2/~1.4.10 and typescript version is ~2.4.2. while it shows the angular cli version as 6.2.9. Try cleaning and reinstalling all the node modules and that might help. Also make sure to install older node version which will makes things easy to make this project work with Angular 4 version.